# XmlWorker does not recognize styles on nested tables

Tags: itext

I have 2 (or more) nested tables: the first is for layout purpose and the others are normal tables with data.

I use the first table because I need to repeat header and footer in each page, so I use

```
repeat-header:yes; 
repeat-footer:yes;
```

css special rules to achieve this, and it works.

I put my document body into  elements.

For data tables I need to give 1px border to the  elements, so I created the css rules to do that:

```
table.data {
border-collapse: collapse;
margin-bottom: 15px;
width: 100%;
}

table.data td {
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #000; 
border-collapse: collapse
}
```

and I set the class of my  element. But it does not have borders.

It looks like overwrite the data style with the external table style, that doesn't have any border so I don't have borders in my internal tables.

My css is into  tag and sometimes I write something inline, but nothing overwrites the 1px border.

I'm using Itext for android and XMLWorker (last version 5.4.4).
My template is HTML and I call from java following method:

```
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml
```

Comment: I'm running into the same kind of problem. If I set the class attributes of all my `td`'s and define a style for that class, then the borders show. Apparently the XMLWorker does not know how to handle CSS hierarchy selectors.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu I tried many ways to do the same thing, but I failed. So, we will wait for a solution here

Answer (score 3):

xmlworker css support is poor, look here:
http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm

Comment: I knew the conformance list, but I used only supported styles. The problem is the inheritance when you use tables

Answer (score 0):

The only fix I found is avoid to use css inheritance and use inline css in every html tag of nested tables.